# javascript challenge, count sheep

Tags: javascript, terminal

Intenté resolver este challenge de javascript, resolví con un for y daba el resultado pero por alguna razón no era correcta la respuesta.

> Consider a list/array of sheep. Each sheep has a name and a color (Separated by commas).
> Make an algorihm that obtains the number of sheep and the name and color of each one and prints in the console the names of the sheep that are res ands whose name also contains the letters n and a, regardless of orden, capitalization or spaces.

> For example:

```
Input:
3
Noah,blue
Euge,red
Ki Na Ma,red

Output: Ki Na Ma
```

> to get and prints values in the console you can use this code example:

```
    const init = {input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout}
const readline = require("readline").createInterface(init)[Symbol.asyncIterator]();

(async () => {
    let line1 = (await readline.next()).value
    let line2 = (await readline.next()).value

    console.log(line1);
    console.log(line2);
})();
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría agradecida. <3

Comment: Hola xBrenx. ¿Qué cosas intentaste y en qué fallaron?

Comment: @caprilo Hola. Intenté esto: 

`const init = {input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout};
const readline = require("readline").createInterface(init)[Symbol.asyncIterator]();

(async () => {
let line1 = (await readline.next()).value
  for (let i = 1; i <= line1.length - 1; i++) {
    if (line1[i][0].toLowerCase().includes("n") && line1[i][0].toLowerCase().includes("a") && line1[i][1] === "red") {
      count = line1[i][0];
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
})();`
Lo raro es que la terminal no corría, por lo tanto ni siquiera me daba pistas de errores.

Comment: ¿en qué estás ejecutando el código javscript?

Comment: @caprilo estoy ejecutando en node.js? visual studio code, supongo que te referís a tecnología.

Comment: Sí, exactamente. Te sugiero que antes lo corras en algún navegador, así te podrás concentrar en la parte de la funcionalidad, y decirnos qué mensaje de error te sale; ya después se puede pasar a nodejs.